# Force application to show status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using an ad client in my project. The Ad client makes the application's status bar hidden. Can I do something to force the application to show status bar?

Answer (score 0):

some code in objective C because i know only objective C

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Hide the status bar
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
    {
        // iOS 7
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }



}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```